# Reshape origin destination data

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I need to turn this data frame :

[image]

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(2,1,4), Flow = c(50,30,20))
```

into a data frame like this :

[image]

```
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1,3), B = c(3,4), AtoB = c(50,20), BtoA = c(20, NA))
```

I am trying to reshape it with dplyr. Is there an existing function or a way to do that ?

Comment: Please share sample data with `dput`

Comment: Sorry I am struggling a bit as I don't ask lots of questions here. I edited my question with dput, is this what you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to create an Identifier column between 'A' and 'B' with labels 'AtoB/BtoA' based on the minimum value in each row, then change the values in 'A', 'B' by taking the `min/max` for each row (`pmin/pmax`) and `spread` the output back to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%      
  mutate(grpIdent = case_when(A == pmin(A, B) ~ 'AtoB', TRUE ~ 'BtoA'),
         A1= pmin(A, B), B1 = pmax(A, B)) %>%
  select(A = A1, B = B1, grpIdent, Flow) %>%
  spread(grpIdent, Flow)
#   A B AtoB BtoA
#1 1 2   50   30
#2 3 4   20   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base` R(This might require introducing a blank or blanks). It is also assumed that the to and fro- values are entered in succession.

```
 new_df<-cbind(df[seq(1,nrow(df), by=2),], df[seq(2,nrow(df), by=2),])[,-c(4,5)]
names(new_df)<-c("A","B","AtoB","BtoA")  
new_df
```

Result:

```
# A B AtoB BtoA
#1 1 2   50   30
#3 3 4   20   30
```